# removing newlines from messy strings in pandas dataframe cells?

Tags: python, string, pandas, split

I've used multiple ways of splitting and stripping the strings in my pandas dataframe to remove all the '\n'characters, but for some reason it simply doesn't want to delete the characters that are attached to other words, even though I split them. I have a pandas dataframe with a column that captures text from web pages using Beautifulsoup. The text has been cleaned a bit already by beautifulsoup, but it failed in removing the newlines attached to other characters.  My strings look a bit like this:

"hands-on\ndevelopment of games. We will study a variety of software technologies\nrelevant to games including programming languages, scripting\nlanguages, operating systems, file systems, networks, simulation\nengines, and multi-media design systems. We will also study some of\nthe underlying scientific concepts from computer science and related\nfields including"

Is there an easy python way to remove these "\n" characters?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

EDIT: the correct answer to this is:

```
df = df.replace(r'\n',' ', regex=True)
```

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df = df.replace('\n','', regex=True)
```

Or:

```
df = df.replace('\n',' ', regex=True)
```

Or:

```
df = df.replace(r'\\n',' ', regex=True)
```

Sample:

```
text = '''hands-on\ndev nologies\nrelevant scripting\nlang
'''
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[text]})
print (df)
                                                   A
0  hands-on\ndev nologies\nrelevant scripting\nla...

df = df.replace('\n',' ', regex=True)
print (df)
                                                A
0  hands-on dev nologies relevant scripting lang
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it still doesn't seem to work, i've copied the code exactly and tried to run it. Then I've tried to only apply it to the column it needs to be applied to: no luck. Then i've tried a for loop looping over every cell of that column and calling cell.replace('n', ''). Also nothing. I  can't use regex in the for loop replace call since I'm iterating over individual strings.

Comment: I think this task are data dependent and are really hard (if simple replace doesnt work). So is possible create [pickle](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-pickle) and send it to my email in my profile? If data are confidental, is possible anonymize it?

Comment: For anyone who finds this later: I think the expression should be: `df.replace(r'\n', ' ', regex=True)`, i.e., don't use two backslashes.

Answer (score 21):

```
df.replace(to_replace=[r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r"], value=["",""], regex=True, inplace=True)
```

worked for me.

Source:

https://gist.github.com/smram/d6ded3c9028272360eb65bcab564a18a

Comment: not sure what value=["",""] does? Gist also doesn't explain. But it worked like charm.

Comment: it matches with values in `to_replace` list. since we have 2 regexes there, value also needs 2 replacements

Answer (score 15):

To remove carriage return (`\r`), new line (`\n)` and tab (`\t`)

```
df = df.replace(r'\r+|\n+|\t+','', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 9):

in messy data it might to be a good idea to remove all whitespaces `df.replace(r'\s', '', regex = True, inplace = True)`.

Answer (score 6):

```
   df = 'Sarah Marie Wimberly So so beautiful!!!\nAbram Staten You guys look good man.\nTJ Sloan I miss you guys\n'

   df = df.replace(r'\\n',' ', regex=True)
```

This worked for the messy data I had.