# Remove '\n' in text in pandas python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, python-2.7

The following code is current code that i use to remove \n in ['text'] column:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')

df['text'].replace('\s+', ' ', regex=True, inplace=True) # remove extra whitespace
df['text'].replace('\n',' ', regex=True) # remove \n in text

header = ["text", "word_length", "author"]

df_out = df.to_csv('sn_file1.csv', columns = header, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

I've tried too from the suggestions:

```
df['text'].replace('\n', '')
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('\n', '').str.replace('\s+', ' ').str.strip()
```

> Output: ' What a smartass! \nLike he knows anything about real estate deals too...'

The code to remove whitespace is working. But not in removing the \n. Anyone can help me on this matter? Thanks.

I've tried to solve based on the suggestion from this link too [removing newlines from messy strings in pandas dataframe cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227748/removing-newlines-from-messy-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-cells) but it's still not working.

Solved:

```
df['text'].replace(r'\s+|\\n', ' ', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: how is `df['text'].replace('\n', '')` working?

Comment: @anky_91 ive tried but it's still the same. But thanks for suggesting

Comment: `\s` matches newlines as well, so it should work, unless your input string contains an actual backslash, followed by a literal `n` instead of a linebreak.

Comment: Does `df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace('\n', '').str.replace('\s+', ' ').str.strip()` do what you're after?

Comment: @TimPietzcker supposedly `\n` in the text that i'd retrieved is a breakline. But how if it has changed to an actual backslash, followed by a literal `n` as u mentioned? How can i work from it?

Comment: @JonClements nope is not working too but Thanks

Comment: @Lily can you [edit] your question then with the offered solutions and their results and how they differ from your expectations please? At this moment... "nope is not working" is not helping anyone see an approach that possibly could. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds as if there is no newline at all, but a ``\`` + `n`. If you use `df['text'].replace(r'\s+|\\n', ' ', regex=True, inplace=True)`, does it disappear?

Comment: @JonClements I suggest closing this as a typo.

Answer (score 4):

Considering one wants to apply the changes to the column 'texts', select that column as

```
df['text']
```

Then, to achieve that, one might use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

This lets one can pass regular expressions, `regex=True`, which will interpret both the strings in both lists as regexs (instead of matching them directly).

Picking up on [@Wiktor Stribiżew suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254186/remove-n-in-text-in-pandas-python#comment91456610_52254186), the following will do the work

```
df['text'] = df['text'].replace(r'\s+|\\n', ' ', regex=True)
```

[This](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/regular-expression-syntax-reference.html?keymap=secondary_windows) regular expression syntax reference may be of help.

Comment: Why do we need two back slashes` for `\\n` but not for `\s`?

Comment: @E.K. In this case, there was no new line, but a \ and a `n`.