# Pandas: How to return rows where a column has a line breaks/new line ( \n ) in its cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to return rows if a column contains a line break and specific word following it. So '\nWord'.

Here is a minimal example

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame([['test1', ' generates the final summary. \nRESULTS We evaluate the performance of ', ], ['test2', 'the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n teamed up to find some food'], ['test2' , 'anthropology with RESULTS pharmacology and biology']])
testdf.columns = ['A', 'B']
testdf.head()

>   A   B
>0  test1   generates the final summary. \nRESULTS We evaluate the performance of
>1  test2   the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n teamed up to find some food
>2  test2   anthropology with RESULTS pharmacology and biology

listStrings = { '\nRESULTS\n'}
testdf.loc[testdf.B.apply(lambda x: len(listStrings.intersection(x.split())) >= 1)]
```

This returns nothing.

The result I am trying to produce is return the first two rows since they contain '\nRESULTS' , but NOT the last row since it doesn't have a '\nRESULTS'

So

```
>   A   B
>0  test1   generates the final summary. \nRESULTS We evaluate the performance of
>1  test2   the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n teamed up to find some food
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below:

```
import re
df1 = testdf[testdf['B'].str.contains('\nRESULTS', flags = re.IGNORECASE)]
df1
#output
A   B
0   test1   generates the final summary. \nRESULTS We eva...
1   test2   the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n teamed up to f...
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually we using `str.contains` with `regex=False`

```
testdf[testdf.B.str.contains('\n',regex=False)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes if they are very confusing text with a lot `\t|\n|\r`, it is not able to find them,
I offer you a regular expression that collects all the cases

Example:
this code will take all the columns WHERE `\t|\n|\r` appear

```py
df_r = df_r[df_r["Name"].astype(str).str.contains(r"\\t|\\n|\\r", "\t|\n|\r",regex=True)]
```

---

the answer has been inspired by: [removing newlines from messy strings in pandas dataframe cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227748/removing-newlines-from-messy-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-cells)

Answer (score 0):

WeNYoBen's solution is better, but one with `iloc` and `np.where` would be:

```
>>> testdf.iloc[np.where(testdf['B'].str.contains('\n', regex=False))]
       A                                                  B
0  test1   generates the final summary. \nRESULTS We eva...
1  test2  the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n teamed up to f...
>>>
```