# Pandas: How to return rows where a column has a line breaks/new line ( \n ) with one of several case-sensitive words coming directly after?

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up to this stackoverflow questions

[Pandas: How to return rows where a column has a line breaks/new line ( \n ) in its cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624067/pandas-how-to-return-rows-where-a-column-has-a-line-breaks-new-line-n-in-i/56624112#56624112)

Which shows how to get a word which follows a new line.

I would now like to return rows where the column can have one of of several case-sensitive words which follows right after a new line.

Here is a minimal example

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame([
    [ ' generates the final summary. \nRESULTS We evaluate the performance of ', ], 
                       [ 'the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n teamed up to find some food'], 
                       ['anthropology with RESULTS pharmacology and biology'],
    [ ' generates the final summary. \nMethods We evaluate the performance of ', ], 
                       [ 'the cat and bat \n\n\nMETHODS\n teamed up to find some food'], 
                       ['anthropology with METHODS pharmacology and biology'],
        [ ' generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We evaluate the performance of ', ], 
                       [ 'the cat and bat \n\n\nBackground\n teamed up to find some food'], 
                       ['anthropology with BACKGROUND pharmacology and biology'],
])
testdf.columns = ['A']
testdf.head(10)
```

will return

```
A
0   generates the final summary. \nRESULTS We evaluate the performance of
1   the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n teamed up to find some food
2   anthropology with RESULTS pharmacology and biology
3   generates the final summary. \nMethods We evaluate the performance of
4   the cat and bat \n\n\nMETHODS\n teamed up to find some food
5   anthropology with METHODS pharmacology and biology
6   generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We evaluate the performance of
7   the cat and bat \n\n\nBackground\n teamed up to find some food
8   anthropology with BACKGROUND pharmacology and biology
```

And then

```
listStrings = { '\nRESULTS',  '\nMETHODS' ,  '\nBACKGROUND' }
testdf.loc[testdf.A.apply(lambda x: len(listStrings.intersection(x.split())) >= 1)]
```

Will return nothing. 
The desired result would return the following rows.

```
A
0   generates the final summary. \nRESULTS We evaluate the performance of
1   the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n teamed up to find some food
4   the cat and bat \n\n\nMETHODS\n teamed up to find some food
6   generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We evaluate the performance of
```

These are rows where the word follows a '\n' and matches the case in the given set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
>>> testdf[testdf['A'].str.contains('\nRESULTS|\nMETHODS|\nBACKGROUND')]
                                                   A
0   generates the final summary. \nRESULTS We eva...
1  the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n teamed up to f...
4  the cat and bat \n\n\nMETHODS\n teamed up to f...
6   generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We ...
>>>
```