# Pandas: Return rows which contain a minimal number of case-sensitive words, and each of those words follows a new line ( '\n' )

Tags: python, pandas

This is a follow up to this stackoverflow question

[Pandas: How to return rows where a column has a line breaks/new line ( \n ) with one of several case-sensitive words coming directly after?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624172/pandas-how-to-return-rows-where-a-column-has-a-line-breaks-new-line-n-with/56624188#56624188)

Which gives a solution to return rows which contain one of several case-sensitive words, which follow a new line '\n'.

I would now like to return rows which contain a minimum number of these case-sensitive words which follow a new line.

In the minimal example below, I am trying to get rows which contain at least Three strings from a particular set.

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame([
    [ ' generates the final summary. \nRESULTS \nMethods We evaluate the performance of ', ], 
                       [ 'the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n BACKGROUND teamed up to find some food'], 
                       ['anthropology with RESULTS \n\n\nMETHODS\n pharmacology and biology'],
    [ ' generates the final summary. \nMethods \nBACKGROUND We evaluate the performance of ', ], 
                       [ 'the cat and bat \n\n\nMETHODS\n teamed up to find some food'], 
                       ['anthropology with METHODS pharmacology and biology'],
        [ ' generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We evaluate the performance of ', ], 
                       [ 'the cat and bat \n\n\nBackground\n teamed up to find some food'], 
                       ['anthropology with \nBACKGROUND with \nRESULTS pharmacology and biology'],
    [ ' generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We \nRESULTS  evaluate \nCONCLUSIONS the performance of ', ]  
])
testdf.columns = ['A']
testdf.head(10)
```

Returns

```
A
0   generates the final summary. \nRESULTS \nMethods We evaluate the performance of
1   the cat and bat \n\n\nRESULTS\n BACKGROUND teamed up to find some food
2   anthropology with RESULTS \n\n\nMETHODS\n pharmacology and biology
3   generates the final summary. \nMethods \nBACKGROUND We evaluate the performance of
4   the cat and bat \n\n\nMETHODS\n teamed up to find some food
5   anthropology with METHODS pharmacology and biology
6   generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We evaluate the performance of
7   the cat and bat \n\n\nBackground\n teamed up to find some food
8   anthropology with \nBACKGROUND with \nRESULTS pharmacology and biology
9   generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We \nRESULTS evaluate \nCONCLUSIONS the performance of
```

And then

```
listStrings = { '\nRESULTS',  '\nMETHODS' ,  '\nBACKGROUND' , '\nCONCLUSIONS', '\nEXPERIMENT'}
testdf.loc[testdf.A.apply(lambda x: len(listStrings.intersection(x.split())) >= 3)]
```

Will return nothing.

The desired result will Only return the last row.

```
9   generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We \nRESULTS evaluate \nCONCLUSIONS the performance of
```

Because that is the only row which contains at least 3 of the specified case-sensitive words which follow a new line.

Comment: Thanks!!!!! Learned a lot today. I think I'll have to get the last check to the @wenyoben , that person was technically ahead (by 18 seconds) this time, and also provided answers to the other questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `str.findall`

```
testdf[testdf.A.str.findall('|'.join(listStrings)).str.len()>=3]
                                                   A
9   generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.findall`:

```
>>> testdf[testdf['A'].str.findall('|'.join(listStrings)).map(len)>=3]
                                                   A
9   generates the final summary. \nBACKGROUND We ...
>>>
```