# Prevent line break in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe imported by `pd.read_excel()`.

When a show it some chacarcters in a cell are printed with breaks like that:

[df result print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZIK0.png)

I have used set_option but still show columns with breaks:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', -1)
```

Is there another way to show the entire text in a cell without breaks?

Comment: Please avoid images in the question.

Comment: Do you want the newlines removed from the dataframe itself or just when printing. Replacing as in this question should work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227748/removing-newlines-from-messy-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-cells. Its likely this is a dup.

Comment: @Sajan the image itself show the behavior I have working on.

Comment: @tdelaney I want to show the entire text in cell without break line like this: AMÉRICO BRASILIENSE

Comment: Right. I asked whether you want to modify the dataframe itself.

Comment: `df.replace("\\n", " ", regex=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: @tdelaney Oh now I understand you. Yes, no problem to change the dataframe. I will test and answer here. Thanks

Comment: The solution you proposed on your quesion solved my problem, so thanks I guess :^D